# How to scan local LAN network?

Tags: c#, networking

I have created a program in C# which scan all PCs in LAN network, and then print out list of IP and computer name of it. This code here I covered in YouTube of someone. But when I try to scan, it always return an error:

```
Additional information: An exception occurred during a Ping request.
```

I try to turn off firewall in all PCs in LAN network, but still have this problem. I spend times to figure out, but still don't know what to do next.

```
    Thread myThread = null;

    public void scan(string subnet)
    {
        Ping myPing;
        PingReply reply;
        IPAddress addr;
        IPHostEntry host;

        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            string subnetn = "." + i.ToString();
            myPing = new Ping();
            reply = myPing.Send(subnet + subnetn);

            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                try
                {
                    addr = IPAddress.Parse(subnet + subnetn);
                    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);

                    txtHosts.AppendText(subnet + subnetn + host.HostName.ToString() + "Up");


                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void cmdScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myThread = new Thread(() => scan(txtIP.Text));
        myThread.Start();

        if (myThread.IsAlive)
        {
            cmdStop.Enabled = true;
            cmdScan.Enabled = false;
            txtIP.Enabled = false;

        }
    }

    private void cmdStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myThread.Suspend();
        cmdScan.Enabled = true;
        cmdStop.Enabled = false;
        txtIP.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps that device isn't there or doesn't respond to pings.

Comment: It is a bad/invalid assumption that all networks are `/24`.

Comment: And what is the exception? The debugger should show that

Comment: Try putting a `try...catch` block around the `myPing.Send()` call and log any error.  That way you can determine if it's ALL pings that are failing, or attempting to ping a single host that fails and stops your program.

Comment: Also, what is the `InnerException` of the exception you get.  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) says that a `PingException` uses the `InnerException` for the exact error.